# Dynamically changing UIView Frame

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a scenario like this:
View B frame depends of View A frame. I am playing around with viewA frame. But the view b frame doesn't get changed because frame is not a object.
So what the workaround, if I need to change the View B frame wrt to View A Frame ie
view B frame gets changed when I change ViewA Frame

Comment: add `UIView B` as subview of `UIView A` will solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

One Solution is `add KVO` for `View A` as it will `notify` when `frame changed` and according to `change` in `frame` of `view A`, `change` `frame` of `view B`

```
[A addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];  //added KVO for View A
```

Method would be:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
 if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
  //change frame of View B according to View A
 }
}
```

**EDIT** : `Remove observer` when not `needed`

```
[A removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In >iOS6, you can try to setup some autolayout constraints, or try this way:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"viewA.frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
```

Be sure to removeObserver on dealloc.  Then, you'll find out when viewA frame changes, and you can implement any set of actions and any functional relationship between viewA and viewB frames...

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"viewA.frame"]) {
        // change viewB's frame according to viewA's frame
        viewB.frame = CGRectOffset(viewA.frame, 20.0, 20.0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the View B frame with respect to View A . Write a method `-(void)ResizeFrame` and put all frame settings in it  and call this function when ever you need to change frame. ie  `ViewB.frame=[ViewA.frame.origin.x,ViewA.frame.origin.y,ViewA.frame.size.width/2,ViewA.frame.size.height/2];` Here i have given division you can change it accordingly.